# OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter doesn't work

Tags: spring, exception, jpa, initialization, lazy-evaluation

I use JSF Primefaces, Spring, Spring Data JPA, and JPA with Hibernate provider.

I want to use OSIV pattern in my 1:N relationship, I don't want it to be EAGER neither to fetch the entities by myself in the service method that access the database.

So I use the OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter. My Spring service method that queries the database is @Transactional annotated.

I think my configuration is ok, but I get the LazyInitializationException of Hibernate.

I've searched a lot on the internet but didn't find the cause of it. ¿Anyone can help me? Thanks.

The log of the exception I get:

```
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] DEBUG (OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter:160) - Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] INFO  (FaseListener:22) - BEFORE RESTORE_VIEW 1
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] INFO  (FaseListener:25) - view root null
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] INFO  (FaseListener:18) - AFTER RESTORE_VIEW 1
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] INFO  (FaseListener:22) - BEFORE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] INFO  (FaseListener:27) - view id = /paginas/categoria/categoriaCrud.xhtml
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] INFO  (FaseListener:18) - AFTER APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] INFO  (FaseListener:22) - BEFORE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] INFO  (FaseListener:27) - view id = /paginas/categoria/categoriaCrud.xhtml
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] INFO  (FaseListener:18) - AFTER PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] INFO  (FaseListener:22) - BEFORE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] INFO  (FaseListener:27) - view id = /paginas/categoria/categoriaCrud.xhtml
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] INFO  (FaseListener:18) - AFTER UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] INFO  (FaseListener:22) - BEFORE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] INFO  (FaseListener:27) - view id = /paginas/categoria/categoriaCrud.xhtml
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] INFO  (CategoriaController:85) - Método editarAction
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] INFO  (FaseListener:18) - AFTER INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] INFO  (FaseListener:22) - BEFORE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] INFO  (FaseListener:27) - view id = /paginas/categoria/categoriaCrud.xhtml
abr 24, 2014 9:49:34 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/paginas/categoria/categoriaCrud.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /paginas/categoria/categoriaForm.xhtml @41,21 value="#{categoriaController.listaClientesCategoria}": Error reading 'listaClientesCategoria' en el tipo controladores.CategoriaController
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:732)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getValue(DataTable.java:867)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:579)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.loadLazyData(DataTable.java:720)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:79)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeTabContent(TabViewRenderer.java:279)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeContents(TabViewRenderer.java:237)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeMarkup(TabViewRenderer.java:127)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeEnd(TabViewRenderer.java:71)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeDynamicBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:92)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:60)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelGridRenderer.java:49)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:115)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:59)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:47)
    at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:51)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Error reading 'listaClientesCategoria' en el tipo controladores.CategoriaController
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: modelo.entidades.Categoria.clientes, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:572)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:551)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toArray(PersistentSet.java:187)
    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:151)
    at controladores.CategoriaController.getListaClientesCategoria(CategoriaController.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:87)
    ... 68 more

[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] INFO  (FaseListener:18) - AFTER RENDER_RESPONSE 6
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] DEBUG (OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter:185) - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] DEBUG (EntityManagerFactoryUtils:435) - Closing JPA EntityManager
abr 24, 2014 9:49:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [Faces Servlet] en el contexto con ruta [/ejemplo] lanzó la excepción [failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: modelo.entidades.Categoria.clientes, could not initialize proxy - no Session] con causa raíz
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: modelo.entidades.Categoria.clientes, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:572)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:551)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toArray(PersistentSet.java:187)
    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:151)
    at controladores.CategoriaController.getListaClientesCategoria(CategoriaController.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:732)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getValue(DataTable.java:867)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:579)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.loadLazyData(DataTable.java:720)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:79)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeTabContent(TabViewRenderer.java:279)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeContents(TabViewRenderer.java:237)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeMarkup(TabViewRenderer.java:127)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeEnd(TabViewRenderer.java:71)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeDynamicBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:92)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:60)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelGridRenderer.java:49)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:115)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:59)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:47)
    at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:51)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] INFO  (FaseListener:22) - BEFORE RESTORE_VIEW 1
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] INFO  (FaseListener:25) - view root null
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] INFO  (FaseListener:18) - AFTER RESTORE_VIEW 1
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] INFO  (FaseListener:22) - BEFORE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] INFO  (FaseListener:27) - view id = /paginas/error/errorServidor.xhtml
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] INFO  (FaseListener:18) - AFTER RENDER_RESPONSE 6
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] DEBUG (OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter:160) - Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] DEBUG (OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter:185) - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
[24 abr 2014 - 21:49:34] DEBUG (EntityManagerFactoryUtils:435) - Closing JPA EntityManager
```

Relevant configuration files:

web.xml (the OEMIV filter is the first of all the filters I have):

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            classpath:/spring-config.xml
            classpath:/springDataJpa-config.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>
...
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
...
  <filter>
    <filter-name>OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>entityManagerFactoryBeanName</param-name>
      <param-value>entityManagerFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Spring config file:

```
<context:annotation-config/>

<context:component-scan base-package="modelo"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean"
    p:jndiName="jdbc/conexionBBDD"
    p:resourceRef="true" />

<bean id="dataSourceProxy"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy"
        p:targetDataSource-ref="dataSource"/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSourceProxy"
        p:packagesToScan="modelo.entidades"
        p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaHibernateAdapter"
        p:jpaDialect-ref="jpaHibernateDialect"
        p:jpaProperties-ref="jpaHibernateProperties" />

<bean id="jpaHibernateAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
        p:database="ORACLE"
        p:databasePlatform="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
        p:showSql="true" />

<bean id="jpaHibernateDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />

<util:properties id="jpaHibernateProperties" location="classpath:jpa-hib.properties" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />

 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

My spring data jpa config file:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="modelo.daos" />
```

Comment: Are the categories and client loaded during the same request? Lazy exceptions can also occur if the entitymanager is not the same. I.e the categories come from the web session and a request later you try to show the clients.

Comment: Hello @Martin Frey. How can I know when are they (categories and clients) loaded and which EntityManager do they use? Maybe I have 2 EMs, I don't know, it is strange... in the log I can see that the OEMIVF opens the EM but I get the Lazy Exeption, and then the OEMIVF close the EM, but then 'EntityManagerFactoryUtils' close again the EM (maybe another EM?)

Comment: I load a datatable in the view with a list of Categoria, each one has a lazy loaded list of Cliente. Then, when I click on the "edit" button of a Categoria row, to show their associated Clientes is when I get the LazyException (but in the log I see that the OEMIVF opens the JPA EM, so I don't know why the exception is fired).

Comment: If I show the clients of each categoria in the datatable row of the category, it works. But I don't want to do that, and I don't understand why it doesn't work showing them in another view clicking the edit button (the OEMIVF opens the JPA EM).

Comment: Basically OSIV works only during the same request. If you load the categories in one request and store them for example in the session to be able to "cache" them for the follow up requests you will store the category with a proxy of clients and this one contains a closed entitymanager. During the next request you get this proxy from the session cache and try to get the clients, it will fail with LIE. One way to check this is using the debugger.

Comment: Hello @Martin Frey... I thought that if in the new request the EM is closed, the filter will open it and retrieve the associated clients. I thought that was the purpose of the filter.

Comment: That's not it's purpose. OSIV will keep the entitymanager open during one request. The idea is to be able to load lazy objects during the render phase. Normally an entitymanager lives only during one transaction. (I.e a service method if you have this one transactional). If you want to reuse an entity from another request you will have to call "merge" for this entity to connect it again to the current entitymanager.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Martin Frey. I think that the solution I will take is don't to use the OEMIVF and initialize the lazy collections at the service method (by calling size method for example). This would solve both the OEMIVF "problem" across request, and the Lazy Exception "problem" in just one request. Besides that, I don't know where I would call "merge", as I use Spring Data JPA Repositories (I don't access the EM by myself). How do you solve this kind of problems in your projects? I thank you very much your help, you made me understand the problem I have. Thanks a lot.